# Missing assembly after build

Tags: c#

I have 5 projects in my C# solution.

1. Common
2. DataAccess.
3. UI
4. Components
5. Test

I can add a reference to Components.dll. But, when I run the solution, I got the error:

> The type or namespace name 'Components' does not exist.

The `Components.dll` is already present in the references folder.

Would you please help me?

Here is build output:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Comps, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
  Comps -> ..\Ashyaneh\Comps\bin\Release\AshyanehComps.dll
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Interfaces, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  Interfaces -> ..\Ashyaneh\Interfaces\bin\Debug\AshyanehInterfaces.dll
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Common, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  Common -> ..\Ashyaneh\Common\bin\Debug\AshyanehCommon.dll
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Web, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  Web -> E:\My Programming 1391\HRShojaieWebAppRC2\Ashyaneh\Web\bin\Web.dll
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
warning MSB3253: The referenced assembly "AshyanehComps.dll" could not be resolved
because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework
".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies
not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.
  Test -> ..\Ashyaneh\Test\bin\Debug\Test.exe
========== Rebuild All: 5 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Is Components project added as a reference in any of these other projects? In which of these five projects is error reported? Can you successfully build each of them separately?

Comment: Yes, each of them build successfully.

Comment: No, Components project added as a reference only in Test project.

Comment: This is because your main project target framework is .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile, but "Components" target framework is .NET Framework 4.0, change the target framework of your main project to be ".NET Framework 4.0" And not ".NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile", my answer below describing how to do that.

Comment: All project target is .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is your problem:

*The referenced assembly "E:\My Programming 1391\HRShojaieWebAppRC2\Ashyaneh\Comps\bin\Release\AshyanehComps.dll" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"*

Assuming you are trying to run .NET 4.0 you are compiling against the "lightweight", Client Profile, Base Class Libraries. You need the full-blown Framework Class Libraries for System.Web to be included.

**Solution**

In order to change this right click on the Project for AshyanehComps.dll > click properties > click the "Application" tab > change the "Target Framework" to ".NET Framework 4".

Just to be safe I would follow the above steps for all of the projects in your solution and you should be good.

Comment: Very well. Done. It's now OK. Problem was solved. Thank you very very much dear friend.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have components added as a reference in every place it needs to be by right clicking on the project that has the error and clicking "Add Reference" and choosing a project reference?

If the above is done I would follow this process:

- Save All
- Close Visual Studio
- Delete the BIN and OBJ folders in each of your projects
- Restart VS
- Try again

If it still doesn't work then you likely need to adjust your build order. Right click on the solution and ensure that each of your projects are building in the correct dependency order and make sure that you don't have any circular dependencies.

Comment: tank you, i do all steps, but it doesn't work. what does circular dependencies mean?

Comment: only one off the projects dll make this error if i add a reference to it.. it's components.dll.  i rename it, but still doesn't work

Comment: Interesting... Try posting your MS build output to your original post, that should be more useful (It comes through on the "Output" tab)

Answer (score 0):

verify that you save your csproj when you commit your solution, because your csproj contain your references :

Comment: tank you for response, all csproj are saved...the problem exists yet

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your main application target framework is not set to .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile.
If it set to this, change it and set it to .Net framework 4.0.

You can see how to change 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, you have 5 projects.
You have to determine which **'Components'** is reported not exist in which particular project ?

Then you go to the project reference to add (re-add if it was there to let the VS refrence cache generated) that to the project. Check if you need to "copy to local" option or either verify the global assembly path.

Now you are done for all reference, if the problem still arised, 
check on your project code (specific line) to see why it is not working. Post the MS Build output and it will tell.

Comment: I have Email, Cache, Configuration and some other classes in Components.csproj. When I add a reference to Components.dll, it was added and all its classes are accessable(!). but, when i want to run(F5), the type or namespace does not exist error are occurred.

Answer (score 0):

- When you are adding 'Components' project to other projects as reference,
  in 'Add Reference' screen add your reference in Project tab not
  Browse tab in 'Components' project output path(Components.dll).
- Then, clear your solution and build your 'Components' project.
- If you have errors in your 'Components' project solve them.
- At last build your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're applications targeted framework is 4.0 Client Profile like mine was.  The solution unless you are using something specific to 4.0 is to drop it down to 3.5 and the errors go away.  Thanks Microsoft.