# Deployed Code Cannot Find A Library Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have written an application in Visual Studio Express 2010 that has a reference to a Class library that I coded.  For this reference I have set the "Copy Local" property to true but when I deploy this code outside of the development directory it throws an error because it cannot find the library.  I thought Copy Local = True took care of this.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: How do you deploy your application? "Copy Local" is a Visual Studio functionality.

Comment: I had a problem some things like yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263500/missing-assembly-after-build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Copy Local = true` ensures that the referenced assembly is copied to the output directory on build. You still need to ensure that the referenced library gets deployed, whatever deployment method that may be.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that building the solution bundled all the code into the executable.  I have deployed the .dll for the library and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, copy local only applies when you compile in Visual Studio. If you're using Visual Studio deployment, you may need to right click the deployment project and hit 'Refresh Dependencies.'